# Can I change the ID number on a Pocketstation with anything other than a PDA with infrared output?

Tags: ps1, final-fantasy-8

I bought a Pocketstation some time ago, since I'm a big fan of Final Fantasy 8, and wanted to get everything in the game.  I read up on guides, and one(possibly the only one) mentioned that the code that was set on the Pocketstation determined what grade of items you could get in Chocobo World, with most codes not even able to get "A" grade items.  However, if you battled someone else with a better code, you could take theirs, and change the inherent code the device was initially programmed with.  Barring that, you could force a code change with PDAs that used infrared signal, and even set the code to the best possible one, 211, without much trouble.

Well, I have no such PDA, but I *do* have a tiny computer known as a smart phone at arm's length at almost all times. Is it possible to do anything like that with this device that basically amounts to a tricorder, at this point?

'Cause that'd be sweet.

Comment: You'd need an infrared transmitter, an app that would allow you to send raw data over it and you'd have to know the data protocol used by the Pocketstation.

Comment: I tried to import a pocketstation from Japan when FF8 launched, it never arrived and the importer vanished and I lost my cash. :-(

Comment: Alright, I see.  It's going to cost more than the Pocketstation itself to turn it into a _good_ Pocketstation.  I guess it's not worth it, then.  A man can dream though... a man can dream.

Comment: The Steam PC version came with a port of the minigame which certainly was giving me A level items.  (I'm talking about the original Steam release here, not the remaster that's due out next week.  Though it wouldn't be shocking if that also includes it.)